# Connecting website database to mailchimp lists

Tags: php, database, laravel, mailchimp

I've got a website with a simple form where users can signup, in this form users have to specify a certain group that they want to be a part of.

What i want to do is to connect a group to a mailchimp list so that whenever someone signs up for this particular group they automatically get added to the mailchimp list. They also need to receive the very first campaign.

Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write my code for me" site. If you give us what you have tried, we can help improve it.

Comment: told you i already have a simple form and database set up, i just need help getting started with this, where did i ask for anyone to write code for me?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a [skovmand/mailchimp-laravel](https://github.com/skovmand/mailchimp-laravel) package for it:

**Step 1: Adding the dependency to composer.json**

Add this to your composer.json in your Laravel folder. Note: Adding this dependency will automatically setup `"mailchimp/mailchimp": "~2.0"` too.

```
"require": {
    ...
    "skovmand/mailchimp-laravel": "1.*",
    ...
}
```

**Step 2: Register the service provider**

Register the service provider in `config/app.php` by inserting into the providers array

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Skovmand\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

**Step 3: From the command-line run**

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Skovmand\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider"`

This will publish config/mailchimp.php to your config folder. In this file, insert your Mailchimp API key:

```
'apikey' => 'your-api-key-here',
```

**Usage example**

```
class NewsletterManager 
{
    protected $mailchimp;
    protected $listId = '1234567890';        // Id of newsletter list

    /**
     * Pull the Mailchimp-instance (including API-key) from the IoC-container.
     */
    public function __construct(Mailchimp $mailchimp) 
    {
        $this->mailchimp = $mailchimp;
    }

    /**
     * Access the mailchimp lists API
     */
    public function addEmailToList($email) 
    {
        try {
            $this->mailchimp
                ->lists
                ->subscribe(
                    $this->listId, 
                    ['email' => $email]
                );
        } catch (\Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed $e) {
            // do something
        } catch (\Mailchimp_Error $e) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp has this option already built in depending on your package.

http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/create-signup-forms-and-response-emails

It's actually easier to use the Mailchimp form builder which gives you the option to add them to a list or multiple lists and then send a "Welcome Email" or auto-response once someone completes the form.

Then you simply embed the form to your website.